# Make connection with excel with rapidly data fetching

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, gridview, connection

I am making a website for trading application in which the trading feed is coming from a source in Excel spreadsheet. I have to show data from Excel spreadsheet in a GridView, but when I make a connection, it is lost due to rapidly changing data. In the Excel spreadsheet, each cell changes its value 1-3 times per one second.

I have to make this application also for Windows.

Comment: When you make WHAT kind of connection? What are you currently doing?  DDE? DDE is known to be slow.  If you're using COM/OLE or some kind of .NET wrapper, then it should be fast. You need to show your code.

Comment: Are you sure you need to grap the data from excel? This sounds, well, interesting. You might be able to add a macro to the excel which is called on each update of the data which actively distributed the new data to some sort of queue. From there the website & the win app could get their data. That way you can also easily change the data source once you do not need excel as a source any more.